# In Rails when using the Devise gem, how to log failed logins and lockups?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, public-activity

I use the `Devise` to handle the authentications in my app and have `public_activity` to record things and have a log. Now I need to add a record to the log when a failed login occurs and when a account gets locked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Warden's `after_authentication` hook as devise is built on warden. Put this in an `config/initializers/devise_hooks.rb`:

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user, auth, opts|
  # do something with user
end
```

Read details in [wardens wiki](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Callbacks)

Comment: after_authentication is called when the authentication is successful before_failure would be a better choice to see failed attempts